# Is it possible to send multi-touch events to windows from Matlab?

Tags: windows, matlab, multi-touch

I have an a demo in Matlab that I would like to send multiple touch events from (to the operating system) as if someone was touching the screen. I want to be able to supply 5 to 10 touch points and their coordinates.
How can this be done on a machine without a touch input hardware but with the touch drivers installed ... ?

Comment: Can you use the `java.awt.robot` class to simulate touch input?

Comment: I can send single mouse position events using java.awt.robot but not multiple (as far as I know)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems to be somewhat more complicated than one might imagine.
Currently the best solution on Windows 7 uses MultiTouchVista and TUIO.

1) Download [MultiTouchVista](http://multitouchvista.codeplex.com/)

2) Activate Pen and Touch

3) Run Multitouch.Service.Console.exe

4) Run Multitouch.Driver.Console.exe

5) Run Multitouch.Configuration.WPF.exe and choose TUIO

6) Download [oscsend](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/matlabcentral/fileexchange/31400-send-open-sound-control-osc-messages/content/oscsend.m) for sending OSC frames as required by TUIO.

Here is some sample code to send 5 touch points to the screen in a loop.

```
clear all
u = udp('127.0.0.1',3333);
fopen(u);
fprintf('Opened\n');
pause(0.5);
n = 0;

%%
pause(5);
while 1

    x = 0.5;
    y = 0.5;

    for t = -0.2:0.01:0.2
        oscsend(u , '/tuio/2Dcur' , 'siiiii' , 'alive' , 5*n,5*n+1,5*n+2,5*n+3,5*n+4);
        oscsend(u , '/tuio/2Dcur' , 'sifffff' , 'set' , 5*n,   x + t, y - 0.2, 0, 0, 0);
        oscsend(u , '/tuio/2Dcur' , 'sifffff' , 'set' , 5*n+1, x + t, y - 0.1, 0, 0, 0);
        oscsend(u , '/tuio/2Dcur' , 'sifffff' , 'set' , 5*n+2, x + t, y      , 0, 0, 0);
        oscsend(u , '/tuio/2Dcur' , 'sifffff' , 'set' , 5*n+3, x + t, y + 0.1, 0, 0, 0);
        oscsend(u , '/tuio/2Dcur' , 'sifffff' , 'set' , 5*n+4, x + t, y + 0.2, 0, 0, 0);        
        oscsend(u , '/tuio/2Dcur' , 'siiiii' , 'fseq' ,  5*n,5*n+1,5*n+2,5*n+3,5*n+4);
        pause(0.01);        
    end

    n = n + 1;
    fprintf('Sent\n');
    pause(1);
end

%%

fclose(u);
fprintf('Closed\n');
```

You might not see anything except for a moving mouse but the operating system is receiving the touches and if you open one of [Microsoft's Touch-Pack](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=17368) examples you can see the multiple touch points. Heres a screen shot from [FruitNinja Lite](http://www.appup.com/app-details/fruit-ninja-lite)

[image]